Center an image using absolute position in React Native
I'm new to React Native, and am trying to center an <Image /> component within a larger <View />, per below:
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';

<View
  style={{
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "relative",
  }}
>
  <Image
    style={{
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      margin: "auto",
    }}
    source={spinner}
  />
</View>;


But instead of being centered, it is positioned on top left within <View />.
The above css would have worked in HTML, but what am I missing for React Native? Btw I have to use absolute position for the Image to overlay on other components inside <View />.
Thank you,

that's because you've added top: 0; left:0...

You've assigned top and left values to 0 which positions it to top-left.
This should work:
<Image
  style={{
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    position: "absolute",
    margin: "auto",
  }}
  source={spinner}
/>


Adding this on your child element along with absolute will solve the issue.
top: '50%',
left: '50%',
transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
<SafeAreaView>
      <View
          style={{
            width: 48,
            height: 48,
            alignSelf: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            position: "relative",
            borderColor: '#000',
            borderWidth: 1
          }}
        >
          <Image
            style={{
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              position: "absolute",
              top: '50%',
              left: '50%',
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
            }}
            source={{uri: 'image_url_here'}}
          />
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>


I think the easiest would be to think of a new View as your overlay instead of the Image itself.
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: 48,
        height: 48,
        alignSelf: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      {/* Overlay */}
      <View
        style={{
          ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
          }}
          source={spinner}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

If the alignSelf, justifyContent, and alignItems on the parent View were added for the Image, they can be removed.
